# IIS issues with urlrewrite

Tags: web, iis, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to set up urlrewrite for my API.
Now my site is like:

```
cookhamburger.php?topping=mayo&how=grill
cookpasta.php?topping=ragu&how=aldente
```

Given I have many utilities already bound to theese urls I want to stay compatible, but also I want to extend my site.

hence I made a generic handler that takes the "food" as a parameter

```
cooksomething.php?what=pasta&topping=ragu&how=aldente
```

to achive this I have to remap old urls to the new handler using a regex like

```
cook(.*)\.php\?(.*)
```

to match it
and a remap like the following

```
cooksomething.php?what={R:1}&{R:2}
```

Now my issue is that once I go to the url:

```
http://localhost/cookhamburger.php?topping=mayo&how=grill
```

I got an error

```
Modulo «module»            IIS Web Core
Notifica                   MapRequestHandler
Gestore «handler»          PHP 
Codice errore «error»      0x80070002
```

this is my web.config for the broken configuration:

```xml
    <configuration>
        <system.webServer>
            
            <rewrite>
                <rules>
                    <clear />
                    
                    <rule name="Handler remap" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="^cook(.*)\.php\?(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
                        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="Rewrite" url="cooksomething.php?what={R:1}&amp;{R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
                    </rule>
                    
                </rules>
            </rewrite>
        </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

but the following remap, for example,

```
(.*)\?(.*)

cooksomething.php?{R:1}&{R:2}

/hamburger?topping=mayo
```

works

Comment: You can refer to the documentation to create rules : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: That's how I got here